# Can't Copy from NTFS to EXT4

Tags: ntfs, dolphin, cp

Running Kubuntu 18.04.01 bionic.  I've tried Dolphin and the terminal but can't copy a .MOV file from 1TB usb drive NTFS to EXT4 on an Asus laptop.  The permissions of the NTFS file show world rwx and owner as me when viewed with Dolphin.  Both filesystems are mounted.

The message I get from the command:

```
$ cp -a /media/mark/3D9578B26267F622/boat/MVI_3734.MOV /home/mark/Videos/boat/MVI_3734.MOV
cp: error reading '/media/mark/3D9578B26267F622/boat/MVI_3734.MOV': Permission denied.
```

(The odd looking directory "3D95..." is the how the NTFS partition is mounted in Kububtu.)

The permissions in Dolphin looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Any ideas on why this is not copying from NTFS to EXT4?

Comment: Do you have rw permission for the directory `/media/mark/3D9578B26267F622/boat`?

Comment: I'm running Kubuntu 18.04.01 LTS.

Comment: Yes, I have permission to read and write to /media/mark/3D95.../boat.  The .MOV video files will not run using VLC media player or KMplayer.

Comment: VLC media player comes back with error..."Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///media/mark/3D9578B26267F622/boat/MVI_3734.mov'. Check the log for details."

Comment: Based on available info, must be an issue with the ntfs volume. It mounts properly, but apparently provides read errors. Might also indicate hardware failure. Have the ntfs partition checked on a Windows system (and properly unmount or fully shut down Windows). If the issue persists, then it may be a hardware issue.

Comment: @vanadium Please add that as an answer, thanks!

Comment: I checked the .mov files in WIndows 10 and they open properly.  However, I turned off "fast boot" and permissions changed from "mark" to "root".  I then used sudo chown -R mark:mark /media/mark

Comment: I checked the .mov files in WIndows 10 and they open properly. However, I turned off "fast boot" and permissions changed  from "mark" to "root".  I then used sudo chown -R mark:mark /media/mark to change permissions.  The ls command indicated all files from /media/mark have ownership changed to "mark" but VLC will not run the .mov file.  @vanadium I can open and view a .png file I created in Kubuntu and saved in /media/mark so I don't think this is a hardware issue.

Comment: Here is the output of ll for /media/mark/3D9578B26267F622/boat... mark@mark-TP300LDB:/media/mark/3D9578B26267F622/boat$ ll
total 3119420
drwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark       4096 Jan 10 22:06 ./
drwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark       4096 Jan 10 18:48 ../
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark  716887980 Apr 11  2017 MVI_3734.mov*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark  615716976 Apr 26  2017 MVI_3777.MOV*
-rwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark      52657 Jan 10 22:06 Screenshot_20190110_220520.png*  The screenshot file was created in Kubuntu and it opens.  The .MOV files were created in Windows 10 and do not open.

Comment: I'm wondering if the issue has something to do with the /media dir being owned by root?

Comment: I try to copy the .mov file from ntfs to the laptop running Kubuntu...cp MVI_3734.mov /home/mark/Videos/MVI_3734.mov
cp: error reading 'MVI_3734.mov': Permission denied
This seems odd because the permissions on the MVI are ...-rwxrwxrwx 1 mark mark  716887980 Apr 11  2017 MVI_3734.mov*

Comment: Did you check/repair the file system using the Windows file system checking tools? You did not mention this explicitly.

Comment: @MarkS Please [edit] the question if you want to add details or updates. Command output is impossible to read in comments.

Comment: Okay, things are working now.  The windows .MOV files were originally encrypted on a USB drive using Windows encryption.  I supplied the password to open the encrypted and copied them to the USB unencrypted ntfs partition thinking they are now unencrypted.  Wrong!  I opened WIndows 10 and right clicked properties and discover the files are encrypted although Windows10 will open the files without a password.  I right click on the .MOV files and select "file permissions"? than "personal use"? and encryption is turned off and files open in Kubuntu.

Comment: @wjandrea I tried hitting enter for a new line but doesn't work.  I need to figure out the syntax.

Comment: @MarkS Comments don't support line breaks. Like I said, details and updates should be [edit]ed into the question. Also please put your solution into an answer (yes, you can answer your own question).

Answer (score 1):

The solution here is more of how to properly save a BitLocker encrypted file from NTFS running Windows 10 to an EXT4 unencrypted filesystem running Kubuntu Linux.  Opening the BitLocker encrytped disk and saving to an EXT4 unencrypted partition will NOT yield an unencrypted EXT4 file. You must first change permissions under Windows 10 to "personal".[image]

Enabling or disabling "fast boot" in the BIOS had no effect.